# How can I edit an entity model?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to edit an entity's model in Minecraft. Is there any way to do this? I understand that Optifine can be used, but is there another way?

For example, say I wanted to remove the head of a zombie model. How could I do that?

I've tried to search the appdata folders, and have downloaded model makers, but don't know how to use them without Optifine. I would be fine using it, but I'm using update 1.14.

Comment: In your case you could just make those parts of the texture transparent.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some basic instructions on how to use block/item models instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, this feature isn't implemented yet, you can only remodel blocks and items: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Model&oldid=1364501))

Instead, you can remodel a block and use a `falling_block` entity. I honestly have no idea how custom models work, but there are tutorials online. You can apply it to this case for example like this:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,BlockState:{Name:"stone"}}
```

Of course you'll want to use something that doesn't appear anywhere else normally. If you can't guarantee that, you'll have to try to use items and the `custom_model_data` NBT tag. I think that applies model files like "`stone5.json`".

Comment: Not asking for likes or anything, but I always update all answers with a score of 2 or more to every 1.x.0 version, so you would get notified when this changes. ;)

Comment: Yea... Sadly all entity models are hardcoded. ): Same goes for hitboxes, those are hardcoded too

Comment: Hm, I wonder if remodeling a block and then using it as a falling sand or as a riding entity could work…

Comment: That would work, actually. Falling Sand quite literally just uses block render code directly.

Comment: I'm not sure at the moment, but FallingSandEntity might obey the NoAI flag, too.